# regex how to define that the rule must be the same

Tags: regex

I am searching for a number in this format.

```
[0-9]{3,6}[\-\/]{1}[0-9]{1,3}[\-\/]{1}[0-9]{1,2}
```

Is there a way how to define that there should be always only slash/ or colom- ? In other words, option that first one is - and the second one / should be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `\1` back-reference. This matches the same character (or group) as the first matching group. In this case, the `([-\/])` is the first matching group and `\1` requires to be the same character.

```
[0-9]{3,6}([-\/])[0-9]{1,3}\1[0-9]{1,2}
```

Here is an example: https://regex101.com/r/mKxnUN/1

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to this is to leave for basic regex as-is, but add a look ahead to assert various over-arching requirements:

```
^(?!.*-.*/|.*/.*-)[0-9]{3,6}[\-\/]{1}[0-9]{1,3}[\-\/]{1}[0-9]{1,2}
```

The (negative) look ahead `(?!.*-.*/|.*/.*-)` means "in the following input, there is neither a - then a /, *or* a / then a -.

Although you could probably do it without a look ahead, it's easier to understand with a look ahead, *plus* you can add as many of these as you need as other requirements come along.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an alternation:

```
[0-9]{3,6}(-[0-9]{1,3}-|\/[0-9]{1,3}\/)[0-9]{1,2}
```

It's a basic idea but it works.

Comment: I was thinking if there is something different. The basic seems to be the best.

Comment: @MarioBumbera: other answers are interesting too.